# How to parse float with two decimal places in javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have the following code. I would like to have it such that if price_result equals an integer, let's say 10, then I would like to add two decimal places. So 10 would be 10.00.
Or if it equals 10.6 would be 10.60. Not sure how to do this.

```
price_result = parseFloat(test_var.split('$')[1].slice(0,-1));
```

Answer (score 1134, accepted):

You can use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to do that

```
var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat(yourString).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: toFixed is quite buggy though. Also, here's a better link than w3schools https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: but toFixed() returns number as string, if you will compare numbers, you need to use parseFloat again.

Comment: Use
`var twoPlacedFloat = + parseFloat(yourString).toFixed(2)` to convert to float

Comment: Add parens to get a number instead of string: parseFloat((yourString).toFixed(2));

Comment: JavaScript does not have float data type by default. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures
It has only number data type. So any attempt to covert number to floating value will actually converts number to string/number representation. So real life float value `2.00` is always string/number in javascript.

Comment: When use toFixed(2) for more than 16 digits of 9, it will auto round up, you can try with 9999999999999999 and higher amount

Comment: i had to use something like this:

`parseFloat(parseFloat('1234.56789').toFixed(2))`
since using `toFixed()` seems to return a string.  maybe i am missing something?

Answer (score 89):

If you need performance (like in games):

```
Math.round(number * 100) / 100
```

It's about 100 times as fast as parseFloat(number.toFixed(2))

http://jsperf.com/parsefloat-tofixed-vs-math-round

Comment: With above formula '2.00' returns 2. but I want it to be 2.00.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. If you want the output to be a number instead of a string, then you won't get trailing zeros. So you could use the above converted to a string: 

var twoPlacedFloat = (Math.round(2.002745 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

Comment: WIll the speed increase if I change 100's to 200's?

Comment: If the number of floating point operations stay the same the speed will be the same, so no

Comment: why no simple `number * 1` am I missing something maybe ?

Comment: @ncubica It's about decimal place. If you take 100, then 2 digits after comma, if you take 10, then 1 digit after comma and so on.

Answer (score 59):

When you use `toFixed`, it always returns the value as a string. This sometimes complicates the code. To avoid that, you can make an alternative method for Number.

```
Number.prototype.round = function(p) {
  p = p || 10;
  return parseFloat( this.toFixed(p) );
};
```

and use:

```
var n = 22 / 7; // 3.142857142857143
n.round(3); // 3.143
```

or simply:

```
(22/7).round(3); // 3.143
```

Comment: I wrote a shopping cart program and tried using the toFixed() and the round() methods chained to the parseFloat() method.  Neither of these methods worked with the parseFloat().

Comment: This saved me some to-be headaches. +1 just for that. I had no idea it would turn numbers to strings.

Comment: @Lukas Is not, if do  parseFloat

Comment: This returns 2 if I apply to '2.00' number

Comment: This method is for corrections, not for formatting. For example: `0.1 + 0.2 //  0.30000000000000004` so I need correction for that `(0.1+0.2).round() // 0.3`

Answer (score 21):

To return a number, add another layer of parentheses. Keeps it clean.

```
var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat((10.02745).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Are you missing something in your formula? `var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat(('2.00').toFixed(2))` generates error.

Comment: sorry, had a string variable instead of a number, which toFixed() needs - fixed now. But Rob's answer using Math.round is something to consider in terms of performance.

Comment: This should be a comment to Vlada's answer.

Answer (score 9):

If your objective is to parse, and your input might be a literal, then you'd expect a `float` and `toFixed` won't provide that, so here are two simple functions to provide this:

```
function parseFloat2Decimals(value) {
    return parseFloat(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
}

function parseFloat2Decimals(value,decimalPlaces) {
    return parseFloat(parseFloat(value).toFixed(decimalPlaces));
}
```

Comment: That not work as espected. `parseFloat(parseFloat('10.5').toFixed(2))` return `10.5` espected `10.50`. Also `parseFloat(parseFloat('10.50').toFixed(2))` return `10.5`

Comment: It's a float though, so 10.5 is equal to 10.50

Comment: I know that 10.5 == 10.50 but i need to print to client 10.50 not 10.5

Answer (score 7):

ceil from lodash is probably the best

```
_.ceil("315.9250488",2) 
_.ceil(315.9250488,2) 
_.ceil(undefined,2)
_.ceil(null,2)
_.ceil("",2)
```

will work also with a number and it's safe

Comment: Viable answer if using lodash, I'm currently using underscore.js and currently at 1.9.1 doesn't have a similar function.

Answer (score 7):

You can use .toFixed() to for float value 2 digits

**Exampale**

> ```
> let newValue = parseFloat(9.990000).toFixed(2)
>
> //output
> 9.99
> ```

Comment: How can i do the reverse of this? I have 9.99 and want to get 9.990000

Comment: @Sofiyarao `parseFloat('9.99').toFixed(6)` and you will get 9.990000. `toFixed` determines how many digits are after the decimal

Answer (score 5):

```
parseFloat(parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2))
```

You have to parse it twice. The first time is to convert the string to a float, then fix it to two decimals (but the `toFixed` returns a string), and finally parse it again.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this for my case and it'll work fine.

```js
var multiplied_value = parseFloat(given_quantity*given_price).toFixed(3);
```

Sample output:

> 9.007

Comment: This returns a string, be careful

Answer (score 1):

Please use below function if you don't want to round off.

```
function ConvertToDecimal(num) {
    num = num.toString(); //If it's not already a String
    num = num.slice(0, (num.indexOf(".")) + 3); //With 3 exposing the hundredths place
   alert('M : ' +  Number(num)); //If you need it back as a Number    
}
```

Comment: Use this as following handles integer values as well
function ParseFloat(str, val = 2) {
    str = str.toString();
    if (str.indexOf(".") > 0) {
        str = str.slice(0, (str.indexOf(".")) + val + 1);
    }
    //Following is also an alternative if above does not work
    //str = str.match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0];
    return !isNaN(str) ? Number(str) : 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth: A decimal number, is a decimal number, you either round it to some other value or not. Internally, it will approximate a decimal fraction according to the rule of floating point arthmetic and handling. It stays a decimal number (floating point, in JS a double) internally, no matter how you many digits you want to display it with.

To present it for display, you can choose the precision of the display to whatever you want by string conversion. Presentation is a display issue, not a storage thing.

Answer (score 0):

@sd
**Short Answer:**  There is no way in JS to have Number datatype value with trailing zeros after a decimal.

**Long Answer:** Its the property of `toFixed` or `toPrecision` function of JavaScript, to return the String. The reason for this is that the Number datatype cannot have value like a = 2.00, it will always remove the trailing zeros after the decimal,  This is the inbuilt property of Number Datatype. So to achieve the above in JS we have 2 options

1. Either use data as a string or
2. Agree to have truncated value with case '0' at the end ex 2.50 -> 2.5.
   [image: Number Cannot have trailing zeros after decimal]

Comment: To say there is _no way_ to do it is completely dishonest. Long winded and complicated, sure, but not completely impossible - there are tons of working solutions on this stack alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your price as a string

You can use
Number(string)

for your calculations.

example

```
Number("34.50") == 34.5
```

also

```
Number("35.65") == 35.65
```

If you're comfortable with the Number function , you can go with it.

Comment: With commas is not working

Answer (score -2):

Try this (see comments in code):

```
function fixInteger(el) {
    // this is element's value selector, you should use your own
    value = $(el).val();
    if (value == '') {
        value = 0;
    }
    newValue = parseInt(value);
    // if new value is Nan (when input is a string with no integers in it)
    if (isNaN(newValue)) {
        value = 0;
        newValue = parseInt(value);
    }
    // apply new value to element
    $(el).val(newValue);
}

function fixPrice(el) {
    // this is element's value selector, you should use your own
    value = $(el).val();
    if (value == '') {
        value = 0;
    }
    newValue = parseFloat(value.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2);
    // if new value is Nan (when input is a string with no integers in it)
    if (isNaN(newValue)) {
        value = 0;
        newValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    }
    // apply new value to element
    $(el).val(newValue);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Solution for FormArray controllers
```

Initialize FormArray form Builder

```
  formInitilize() {
    this.Form = this._formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this._formBuilder.array([this.createForm()])
    });
  }
```

Create Form

```
  createForm() {
    return (this.Form = this._formBuilder.group({
      convertodecimal: ['']
    }));
  }
```

Set Form Values into Form Controller

```
  setFormvalues() {
    this.Form.setControl('formArray', this._formBuilder.array([]));
    const control = <FormArray>this.resourceBalanceForm.controls['formArray'];
    this.ListArrayValues.forEach((x) => {
      control.push(this.buildForm(x));
    });
  }

  private buildForm(x): FormGroup {
    const bindvalues= this._formBuilder.group({
      convertodecimal: x.ArrayCollection1? parseFloat(x.ArrayCollection1[0].name).toFixed(2) : '' // Option for array collection
// convertodecimal: x.number.toFixed(2)    --- option for two decimal value 
    });

    return bindvalues;
  }
```

Answer (score -4):

I've got other solution.

You can use `round()` to do that instead `toFixed()`

```
var twoPlacedFloat = parseFloat(yourString).round(2)
```

Comment: @AustinHenley I tried using round() and it didn't work. That's probably why people are down voting. He may be refering to Math.round()

Comment: @Nathan it needs to be used inline, after `parseFloat()` as I've updated the answer by @zsalzbank

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  You may try Math.round(parseFloat(yourString), 2);

Comment: Why not downvote an answer which will never work?
There's simply no such method as `round()` on numbers in js. The real question is who upvoted this.

Answer (score -4):

The solution that work for me is the following

```
parseFloat(value)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't fix to 2 decimal