# html output 2 digits

Tags: javascript, html

I want a simple calculation form.
I took te example of w3schools:

and this is myd adjusted code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form oninput="x.value=parseFloat(a.value).round(2)* parseFloat(b.value).round(2)">
<input type="number" id="a" value="50">
+<input type="number" id="b" value="50">
=<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The output tag is not supported in Internet Explorer.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

when I add the round(2) (form oninput)then it won't work.
if I remove it, it wil work. But if I add some numbers after the decimal, the I get a whole bunch of numbers with lots of zerro's.

I just want a 2 digit output.

can anyone help me please?

I also checkout this link:

[parse float with two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435170/parse-float-with-two-decimal-places)

but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you're multiplying 0.11 and 0.12 - both numbers with two decimal places. The result is 0.132, which has three. And that's assuming you're using numbers that can be represented accurately: most decimal numbers can't.

Rather than rounding the inputs, you should round the output:

```
x.value = (a.value*b.value).round(2);
```

That being said, I don't think `round` is a function to be used like that. I think you need to do this:

```
x.value = Math.round(a.value*b.value*100)/100;
```

Note that because `*` automatically casts its arguments to numbers (unlike `+`), there is no need to explicitly `parseFloat`.