# Onchange to add 2 digits after decimal points

Tags: javascript

I have a receipt that I am working on that does the math for me. I need the results to show up as dollar values.

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="copy1" id="copy1" size="4" maxlength="10" onchange="calculate(this.value)">
<input type="text" name="copycosts" id="copycosts" size="4" VALUE=""/>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(){
var copy1value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("copy1").value, 10);
document.getElementById("copycosts").value = copy1value * 0.50;
}
</script>
```

How do I add 2 decimal places after the multiplication is completed? For instance 13 * 0.50 = 6.5 -- I want it to say 6.50.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse float with two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435170/parse-float-with-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 3):

Use `toFixed()` (which will convert the number to a string):

```
document.getElementById("copycosts").value = (copy1value * 0.50).toFixed(2);
```

If you need to manipulate this number in future, you'll need to use `parseFloat()`:

```
var numFromCopycosts = parseFloat(document.getElementById('copycosts').textContent);
```

References:

- [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to also round the number:

```
(Math.round(copy1value * 0.50 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

**Example**

```
 1.345 will be rounded off to 1.35
```

Added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FQTqk/297/

Comment: Why are you using `parseFloat()` on a number? But +1 for dealing with the rounding issues raised by `toFixed()`.

Comment: yup. also works without `parseFloat`. Since the user is assigning value into an element, `parseFloat()` is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use toFixed:

```
var val = copy1Value.toFixed(2);
```