# AngularJS show 2 decimal point number in number input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I have an issue with displaying form data fields to 2 decimal places. I set the variable `$Scope.theItem.Charge` to 2 decimal places:

```
$scope.theItem.charge = parseFloat(10 * 2).toFixed(2);
```

I then display this data in an editable form field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="charge" id="charge" ng-model="theItem.charge">
```

This works correctly and displays the result, which in this case is `20.00`.
However, because we are saying that this is an input type of "text" the user is able to enter any text into the field, not just numbers. I’d expect to simply do this:

```
<input type="number" name="charge" id="charge" ng-model="theItem.charge" step="0.01">
```

But that returns the following error:

> angular.min.js:119 Error: [ngModel:numfmt]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/ngModel/numfmt?p0=25.00
>   at angular.min.js:6
>   at Array. (angular.min.js:182)
>   at angular.min.js:293
>   at m.$digest (angular.min.js:144)
>   at m.$apply (angular.min.js:147)
>   at l (angular.min.js:98)
>   at D (angular.min.js:103)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.min.js:104)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this? I’ve tried to use the angular directive as described in the link above but that does not work for my scenario.

Comment: Is input type is text or number?

Comment: sorry, please see edits above!!

Comment: You can use toFixed() to do that parseFloat(yourString).toFixed(2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435170/parse-float-with-two-decimal-places

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use [ng-currency](https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency) to handle this problem. It seems to be the most stable way to handle decimals in input fields. `ng-currency` does validate and normalize your `ng-model` in a nice way. So you don't need to fight with fractions or wrong user input data anymore. Please check this **[demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kdKq61hl5bJrZgOjF366?p=preview)**.

#### AngularJS application

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ng-currency']);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {
  $scope.amount = '0.203';
});
```

#### View

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ApplicationController">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" 
             ng-model="amount"
             currency-symbol=""
             ng-currency 
             fraction="2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**--> [Demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kdKq61hl5bJrZgOjF366?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3):

Error: ngModel:numfmt
Model is not of type `number`

You should parse scope.theItem.charge value to float - toFixed returns string:

```
$scope.theItem.charge = parseFloat(parseFloat(10 * 2).toFixed(2));
```

Yes, this is ugly... :)

You can also write directive for parsing string to float:

```
directive('parseFloat', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return '' + value;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And simply use this directive on input field:

```
<input type="number" name="charge" id="charge" ng-model="theItem.charge" step="0.01" parseFloat>
```

Comment: Its not working in my AngularJS app. The frustrating thing is no error is generating either.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. I haven't seen AngularJS for too long :)

Comment: We are having some issue in one of our legacy app built using angularjs. Anyways, thanks for your response.