# Java-script: Trying to add decimal places to my variable

Tags: javascript, php, web-deployment

So I look for answer similar to mine on slackoverflow didn't find anything similar to my problem. I had an issue that the decimal places for my variable below weren't showing 2 decimal places

1) max (which now work)
2) fees (the problem im having)

so I used toFixed on one of the var Max and it works :). But the thing is for using toFixed, toFixed() specifically turns a number into a string. So once the variable max is already a string, calling ' toFixed() ' on it again is an invalid operation. Cause when I tried to use it on "fees"

```
 var max = (principal/2)-fees;
```

From the function, it wouldn't work. Even if I made a new variable like:

```
var Test = fees.toFixed(2)
```

it still wouldn't work from the explanation i explain above and using  https://repl.it/languages to help me. I found about Math.round(fees) as you see below but it gets rid of the decimal and show the whole number only. (the $8 is the fees variable from the code below.)

[image]

Is there some way i can fix the fees variable to show 2 decimal places OR do what im doing below and make a new var = to fees and use some code I never heard of. (still learning about this) thanks

```
<script>
    function CollFee(input, principal, fees){

        var max = ( (principal/2)-fees ).toFixed(2);
        var test = Math.round(fees);
        //var input = this.value;
        //alert(input);

        if(input.value > max){
            input.value = '';
            var text = 'Collection Fee is too high, the total of all collection fees can only be 50% of the Original Principal.';
            text = text + ' Current fee on account is $' +test+ '. THE Maximum additional fee allowed is $' +max;
            alert(text);
            //document.getElementById('collfee_<?php echo $dbid; ?>').value = '';
            //input.value = '';

        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435170/how-to-parse-float-with-two-decimal-places-in-javascript. You can find answer there.

Answer (score 2):

You should really separate your logic from your display.  `.toFixed` should only be used when you've finalized your math and are dealing with your strings.  A secondary problem you are likely experiencing is (if I assume correctly) that because 'input.value' is a string as well, then the comparing input.value to max will give you incorrect results as well.

Try

```
function CollFee(input, principal, fees){

    var max = ( (principal/2)-fees );
    var val = parseFloat(input.value)

    if(val > max){
        input.value = '';
        var text = 'Collection Fee is too high, the total of all collection fees can only be 50% of the Original Principal.';
        text = text + ' Current fee on account is $' +fee.toFixed(2)+ '. THE Maximum additional fee allowed is $' +max.toFixed(2);
        alert(text);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for you help. but i posted the method that works :). thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is a little unclear but probably the problem is that you should format your numbers to proper string, AFTER all calculations are done (so during message creation) - so  this is probably  what you want

```js
function CollFee(input, principal, fees){

  var max = ( (principal/2)-fees );
  var test = Math.round(fees);

  if(input.value > max){
      input.value = '';
      var text = 'Collection Fee is too high, the total of all collection fees can only be 50% of the Original Principal.';
      text =  text + ' Current fee on account is $' 
            + test.toFixed(2) + '. THE Maximum additional fee allowed is $' 
            + max.toFixed(2);
      alert(text);
      //document.getElementById('collfee_<?php echo $dbid; ?>').value = '';
      //input.value = '';

  }
    };
```

```html
Type number and press enter (principal=101, fee=33) (if you type 100 you will see alert)<br>
<input type="text" onchange="CollFee(this, 101,33)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative to .toFixed() is to multiply, round down, and divide, like:

```
let num = 65.4321;
let bigNum = num * 100;
let wholeNum = Math.floor(bigNum);
let currencyFormattedNum = wholeNum/100;
console.log(currencyFormattedNum); // Logs 65.43
```

You can find more details here: https://javascript.info/number

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate all your answer and helpful advice to solve this issue in the future, but none of your methods work, because the pop out didnt show up. I experiment and found this to work. Just to show to you guys thanks.

```
<script>
    function CollFee(input, principal, fees){

        var Smax = ( (principal/2)-fees ).toFixed(2);
        var max = ( (principal/2)-fees )
        var FeeroundP = fees * 1;
        var Feeround = FeeroundP.toFixed(2);
        //var input = this.value;
        //alert(input);

        if(input.value > max){
            input.value = '';
            var text = 'Collection Fee is too high, the total of all collection fees can only be 50% of the Original Principal.';
            text = text + ' Current fee on account is $' +Feeround+ '. THE Maximum additional fee allowed is $' +Smax;
            alert(text);
            //document.getElementById('collfee_<?php echo $dbid; ?>').value = '';
            //input.value = '';

        }
    };
</script>
```