# Having trouble with implementing toFixed() for two decimals behind to comma

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
function computeTotal() {
 var total = 0;
  $('.price-selected-option').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',', '.'));
  })
  $('.total-price').text(total)
}
```

I tried adding .toFixed(2) this way:

```
function computeTotal() {
 var total = 0;
  $('.price-selected-option').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',', '.').toFixed(2));
  })
  $('.total-price').text(total)
}
```

But I (partly) understand this does not work because of .text in the same line. I’m very new to Javascript so any help is highly appreciated.

So to be clear I always want 2 decimals te be displayed behind the comma. Also when for example te price is €8.5, then it should be €8.50 or when it’s €8 it should be €8,00

I looked into [How to parse float with two decimal places in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435170/how-to-parse-float-with-two-decimal-places-in-javascript) but couldn’t find an answer because of my code being different i.e. includes .text

Comment: `total` is a float, that has no fixed decimal. You have to assign it to a variable that is a string

Comment: `toFixed()` is a final formatting function, but not a math function. So use it only if you want to print a float. Btw, numbers like `0.1`do not exists. `(0.1).toPrecision(18)` returns `"0.100000000000000006"`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `toFixed()` is a `Number` method and not a `String` method.

`parseFloat` returns a number, but `toFixed` returns a string. so you need to `parseFloat` again after that.

```js
function computeTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.price-selected-option').each(function() {
    // value is a number
    const value = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',', '.'))
    total += value
  })
  $('.total-price').text(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @nook, I applied your code as in this screenshot but the code doesn’t seem to work yet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TKWlnDECEboclnGMZK6Cgu34st8bvyUA/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Use console.log to see what's the output of each line. I don't use jQuery anymore I don't know its API. This answer was supposed to help you understand why `.toFixed()` doesn't exist on a String. Also, please provide a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) instead of a screenshot.

Comment: I understand the meaning of your answer now. Here’s the pen: https://codepen.io/silvansoeters/pen/OJvKOJw. How do I correctly use console.log? I looked it up and think I’ve wrote it correctly but it doesn’t output the total in the console. Please see the pen for what I’ve done.

Comment: It works. You need to call the function, it won't call itself. https://codepen.io/noook/pen/JjLgMxV

Comment: Okay thanks. Got it. It however still doesn’t output the numbers with 2 decimals behind the comma.. as I asked to set it to in my question. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Updated, actually you need to use `toFixed` at the end, not while calculating

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to learn about `Intl.NumberFormat`. Please check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat). It has plenty of useful options as the second parameter to fine-tune it to your needs.

```js
var numbers = [8, 4312.1, 3.14159, 0.0014, 0.00643];
var results = numbers.map((number) => [ 
  number,
  new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 2, style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number)
]);

results.forEach(([input, output]) => {
  console.log(`${input} => ${output}`);
});
```